# Enable logging for Gradle task on GitHub Actions

Tags: java, github, gradle, github-actions

I am currently running GitHub actions and would like to enable logging for gradle test tasks.

When looking at the gradle action logs, I can see task types with a type of "JavaExec" displaying logs. A task type of "Test" is not displaying any logs except the final result (pass / fail).

How can full System.out.printlns (java) be enabled for a task type of "Test" in gradle on github actions?

I tried the following, but it didnt work-

`test { testLogging.showStandardStreams = true }`